# ckEditor cached its JS folder?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am revisiting an app i wrote a couple years ago that uses ckEditor. Currently using v4.13

Users are wanting to expand the functionality available in the editor.

**I can not get ckEditor to recognize updates to the config.js in the development environment.**

In the ***test*** ***environment***,  the new config.js is recognized and ckeditor does what you would expect.

I have reviewed the SO question 
[CKEditor gem delete cached files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037284/ckeditor-gem-delete-cached-files)
but I think it is something else entirely going on here.

- I went to the ckeditor site and downloaded a FULL configuration and
  completely replaced the entire ckEditor folder in my project. Still
  no change.

  - I renamed the ckEditor folder in my project to c.k.e.ditor (should prevent the editor from doing anything)
    *I have closed and reopened my VisStudio
  - I have closed all the browsers
  - I have deleted all the history associated w/ localhost.
  - I rebooted and even let windows apply 2 hours of updates...
  - I have searched my entire drive for any directories named ckEditor, there are a couple other projects I have using ckEditor. But nothing
    remotely close to the folder structure for this project.
  - The project does use IIS Express. I have stopped and started that.

I am completely dumbfounded.

I am using the pattern  suggested in this  article to wrap the editor in a user control contained in a dll. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/532164/How-to-Integrate-CKEditor-with-ASP-NET

I can get the editor to stop functioning by changing the BasePath attribute to something other than 'ckeditor'.  but it should not work as is since i renamed the actual folder to 'c.k.e.ditor'.

```
   <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKE"
                BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server"
                Height="450px"
                Visible="false" Width="600px">
```

I have posted a comment/question on that page. The post is  6 years old at this point. I hope to get a response but wanted to post here as well.

Has anyone run into this?